# How can I match <titlealts> using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I'm trying to match the following and apply a style to it:

```
<titlealts>some string in here</titlealts>
```

but I just can't seem to get it.

I am able to match the following:

```
<p outputclass="hiddenMeta">Division A</p>
```

by using

```
<xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='hiddenMeta']">
   <fo:block padding-bottom="0pt" padding-top="0pt" 
             margin-top="0pt" margin-bottom="0pt">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

but am having real difficulty trying to match something simple like:

```
<titlealts>1&#x2003;Definition of parental responsibility (Division A Parental Responsibility and Guardianship)</titlealts>
```

I have tried:

```
<xsl:template name="titlealts">
<xsl:template match="titlealts">
<xsl:template match="titlealtws[*]">
```

with no luck at all and am really starting to feel like the noob I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be something else in your XSLT that preventing the match from working. The template `<xsl:template match="titlealts">` should work.

What you can do is start working backwards from `<titlealts>` up through the parent/ancestors and find which template is preventing the match from happening. It could be that you are using an `xsl:value-of` instead of `xsl:apply-templates` in a higher level template.

Comment: It was something in my head that was causing it not to work. I hadn't noticed that I had 3 titles, all with the same content, and I was correctly matching the titlealts and hiding it but not noticing as there were still two other identical titles. Thanks for your help, appreciated.